# Can we use loops in PyScript?

Tags: python-3.x, pyscript

Everytime i tried to use for loop in the PyScript tag, getting an invalid Syntax error :/.What i want to do is (for example):

Python:

```
attr1=['A','B','C']

for i in attr1:
         pyscript.write('output1',i)
```

HTML:

```
<div id='output1'></div>
```

Comment: What we can see here is correct,Please, post a minimal html file with all imports, tags and scripts you are using.

Of course one can use loops in pyscrito, otherwise the language would be of no use at all.

Comment: It's hard to say without more context, but you probably got the indentation wrong somewhere if I were to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just write to the document with print, it doesn't leave you with much choice about the tags for now though. For example,

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
    <py-script>
      l = ["A", "B", "C"]
      for el in l:
          print(el)
      </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Will show

```
A
B
C
```

in the browser.

and it actually generates the following:

```html
<html><head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.20.0/full/pyodide.js"></script></head>
  <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css">
    <script defer="" src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
    <py-script id="py-2536bda2-b41c-7165-4257-38c5d650d507"><div class="parentBox flex flex-col mx-8">
    <div id="py-2536bda2-b41c-7165-4257-38c5d650d507"></div>
    </div>

<div id="py-2536bda2-b41c-7165-4257-38c5d650d507-2">A</div><div id="py-2536bda2-b41c-7165-4257-38c5d650d507-3">
</div><div id="py-2536bda2-b41c-7165-4257-38c5d650d507-4">B</div><div id="py-2536bda2-b41c-7165-4257-38c5d650d507-5">
</div><div id="py-2536bda2-b41c-7165-4257-38c5d650d507-6">C</div><div id="py-2536bda2-b41c-7165-4257-38c5d650d507-7">
</div></py-script>
  

<py-config></py-config></body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed Explanation. To play just around with CSS i used div tag with element id, and explicitly made use of pyscript.write() function.But the Code is working fine with print. :)

Comment: @gsbussan The thing, writing to a single target will overwrite everything if done in a loop and you'll be left with only the last iteration. You should use `pyscript.write` when you have some complex calculations or code running and then write to an anchor with an id.